# Prove that $f$ is continuous at $c$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

> Let $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ and $h:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be continuous functions with $g(c)=h(c)$, $c\in\Bbb R$. Consider
>   $$f=\begin{cases}
> g(x)&x\in\Bbb Q\\
> h(x)&x\in\Bbb R\backslash\Bbb Q \end{cases}$$
>   Prove that $f$ is continuous at $c$.

So basically I have some problem putting my idea into actual proof and I hope perhaps you guys can help me. My idea is to show that if the limit of $f$ approaching $c$ from a rational sequence is the same as the limit of $f$ approaching $c$ from an *irrational* sequence, then $f$ is differentiable at $c$, hence $f$ must be continuous. But I do not know how to put this idea into an actual proof, and help or insights are deeply appreciated.

Comment: In truth, the statement is not clear. I edited it according to my own guess :).

Comment: @some How can $\;f\;$ appear in its own definition? Perhaps you meant $\;h\;$ *in the definition*?

Comment: I assume the second function in the case statement of $f$ should be $h$ not $f$. Assuming that, given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta_1>0$ so that if $|x-c|<\delta_1$ then $|g(x)-g(c)|<\epsilon$, and similarly choose $\delta_2$. (This is just introducing the continuity property explicitly, I haven't really done anything.) My hint is to look at $\delta=\min \{ \delta_1,\delta_2 \}$. What happens with $|f(x)-f(c)|$ when $|x-c|<\delta$?

Comment: Why the statement was edited as such...

Comment: This editing by those other than the author may actually be impairing the clarity of the question.  Many changes are being made to the original problem statement currently, and they change the question fundamentally.

Comment: I've got to admit while I get editing for formatting and grammar and spelling make sense, actuality editing the content "obvious intention" or not seems really presumptuous.

Comment: +1 for comment by fleablood. Content-changing edits can confuse the OP and make the whole question a mess.

Comment: @5xum And to answerers who may answer the wrong question. +1 to fleablood as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is wrong on two counts:

1. You do not cover the case when you approach $c$ from a "mixed" sequence, i.e. from a sequence that contains both rational and irrational elements. There is nothing to show that you can simply ignore those cases.
2. You are trying to prove that $f$ is differentiable at $c$, but this may not be the case. For example, if $g(x)=h(x)=|x|$, then $f$ is **not** differentiable at $0$!

---

I suggest you prove the continuity of $f$ at $c$ using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity. You should, for the most part, only require the definition of what it means that $g$ (and $h$) is continuous at $c$, and everything should fall right out:

You need to prove that:

> For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$.

You already know that:

1. For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta_1>0$ such that $|x-c|<\delta_1$ implies $|g(x)-g(c)|<\epsilon$.
2. For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta_2>0$ such that $|x-c|<\delta_2$ implies $|h(x)-h(c)|<\epsilon$.

You also know that $|f(x)-f(c)|$ is equal to either $|g(x)-f(c)|$ **or** $|h(x)-h(c)|$.

Comment: Ah I see. So allow me to summarize to see if my understanding is correct. So basically the idea is to apply the  $\epsilon - \delta$ definition to both branches since $f(x)$ is either one of the branches, and the key here is choosing the right $\delta$ so that it "fits" into both cases.

Comment: @some1fromhell Correct. Also, let me remind you that if $x<a$ and $x<b$, then $x<\max(a,b)$.

Answer (score 2):

To show that the limit of $f$ in $c$ is $f(c)$ you need to show that for every $\epsilon > 0$  there's $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x\in (c-\delta , c+\delta)$ you have that $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$.

Since $g$ and $h$ are both continuous at $c$ and equal $f(c)$ in that point, you have that for $\epsilon > 0$ you have $\delta _1 >0$ such that for $x\in (c-\delta _1 , c+\delta _1)$ it holds that $|g(x)-f(c)| <\epsilon$ and $\delta _2 >0$ such that for $x\in (c-\delta _2 , c+\delta _2)$ it holds that $|h(x)-f(c)| <\epsilon$.

Now by taking $\delta = \min\{\delta _1,\delta _2\}$ you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You started off correctly and then somehow jumped on differentiation which does not seem to make sense here. If we approach $c$ via rational numbers then the limit is taken using the function $g$ and since it is continuous at $c$ the limit is $g(c)$. Similarly when we approach $c$ using irrational values then the limit is $h(c)$ and since $g(c) = h(c)$ you can see that the limit of $f$ as $x \to c$ is same whether we approach via rationals or irrationals.

Next we need to ensure that the limit is also equal to $f(c)$. For this we need to check the case when $c$ is rational and the case when $c$ is irrational. Clearly if $c$ is rational then $f(c) = g(c)$ and hence the limit is equal to $f(c)$. Similarly we deal with the case when $c$ is irrational.

A much shorter/better proof goes like this. Let us first take the case when $c$ is rational. Then $f(c) = g(c)$. Now both $g, h$ are continuous at $c$ and $g(c) = h(c) = f(c)$ hence we can get all the values of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ to be arbitrarily close to $f(c)$ by taking $x$ sufficiently close to $c$. Since the values of $f(x)$ are basically values of $g(x), h(x)$ depending or the rationality/irrationality of $x$ it follows that values of $f(x)$ can be made arbitrarily close to $f(c)$ by choosing $x$ sufficiently close to $c$. This means that $f$ is continuous at $c$. Same argument works when $c$ is irrational.